# Why won't AWS let me create a route to a private vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, routing, amazon-vpc

I have a public VPC vpc-xxxx63

I have a private VPC called vpc-xxxx99

I want to route traffic from the public vpc to the private vpc

I go to VPC Dashboard -> Route tables

Select the public VPC and select Edit

The only option under the target field auto complete is the igw-xxxx internet gateway. How do I route to a VPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your question I have understood you have two different VPC public and private, So frist you need to create a VPC peering between both the VPC and then try updating the route table of private vpc to allow traffic from public vpc.

Comment: Ok. Good advice. Set that up now and accepted the peering request. Added route but still cannot ssh from first vpc to second. Just times out.

Comment: Had to add a route also in the opposite direction